# How recode unicode char like "\xe9" and "<e9>" to "é" in R?

Tags: r, string, unicode

I read "csv" file where one field has values like "J\xe9rome" or "Jrome" at the same time. How to read this file to have values like "Jérome" or make characters transformation then?

I tried to use

```
   df <- fread(file_name, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying that "J\xe9rome" is literally written in the text file with the slash and everything?? How was the file created? Some program must have oddly escaped the non-ascii characters. But that type of encoding does not look like utf-8 encoding, that looks like latin-1 so trying to read it as utf-8 probably won't work. What OS are you on? You need to be very careful with encodings when using non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I use csv file "as is" (no option to control its savings). The chars "<e9>" and "\xe9" used randomly. So, I need to fix it in some way

Comment: @MrFlick df <- fread(file_name, encoding = "Latin-1") is works. Thanks!